# How do I create a table in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I want to create a table called `quiz_mailing_list` in my database in SQL Server 2005.

With Fields:

```
id              auto-increment primary key
email           varchar(256)
optIn           tinyint
referringEmail  varchar(256)
```

Here is what I tried:

```
CREATE TABLE quiz_mailing_list(
        id int identity(1,1) primary key,
        email varchar(256),
        optIn bit
        referringEmail varchar(256))
```

I get this error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'referringEmail'
```

How do I create a table in SQL Server 2005?

Comment: @Tony I'm sure there are schools using SQL Server 2005...but these commands would be valid for 2008, 2005, 2000, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
USE YourDatabaseName
GO

CREATE TABLE quiz_mailing_list (
    id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    email varchar(256),
    optIn bit,
    referringEmail varchar(256))
```

Comment: i get an error.  see the updated post.  im not in school, so i won't be tagging any homework related questions

Comment: @Lukasz You're right...my hands got ahead of my head. I editted with the correct usage.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick...

```
USE [whatever_db]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[quiz_mailing_list]    Script Date: 09/11/2009 17:06:47 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[quiz_mailing_list](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [email] [varchar](256) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [optin] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [referringEmail] [varchar](256) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
```

Answer (score 1):

Sir you are missing a comma ( ,) after *optIn bit*. Try below code

```
CREATE TABLE quiz_mailing_list(
    id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    email varchar(256),
    optIn bit,
    referringEmail varchar(256))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use MyDatabase
go
create table Quiz_Mailing_List
(
   ID int identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
   Email varchar(256),
   Size tinyint,
   OptIn bit,
   ReferringEmail varchar(256)
)
```

[MSDN documentation on CREATE TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258255(SQL.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

### How to create a new table in SQL Server 2005 with the GUI:

If you don't understand SQL, you can use the Graphical User Interface walk you through creating a new table this way:

1. Right click the "Tables" folder under your database.
2. Choose "New Table".
3. Enter in a new column names and data types.  You can choose properties of your columns from the properties window.
4. Click the save button or use Ctrl-S.
5. Left click the "Tables" button in object explorer under the database you created it in, and you should see your table.

### How to create a new table in SQL Server 2005 using SQL:

1. Click the "New Query" button in the upper left.
2. Add this code to the query window:

   ```
   use yourdatabase
   go
   create table Quiz_Mailing_List
   (
      ID int identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
      Email varchar(256),
      Size tinyint,
      OptIn bit,
      ReferringEmail varchar(256)
   )
   ```
3. Select the text and press F5 to execute.
4. It should say: "Command(s) completed successfully."
5. Left click "Tables" on the Object Explorer pane to see your created table.

Answer (score -2):

The command to "use a database" in a T-SQL script is

```
USE DatabaseName
```