# How to add table in the existing database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005

I have developed windows application using C# with SQL server 2005.

I have deployed this application with  database.

My question is:

my source database is one location and also my duplicate database in another location.  i write c# code using stremreader to duplicate it. after some days later i alter/ new table are created. suppose these changes also do to duplicate table without data loss.

I want to add one more table in the existing database without affecting the existing data.

Comment: Run some sort of update process that fires a CREATE query to the database. Creating a new table wont affect other tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a new table doesn't affect other tables and/or the data. Just run the `CREATE TABLE` sql and you'll be fine.

Comment: my source database is one location and also my duplicate database in another location.  i write c# code using stremreader to duplicate it. after some days later i alter/ new table are created. suppose these changes also do to duplicate table without data loss.

Answer (score 0):

There is no effect of adding a new table in database to others table,

if you are creating a foreign key in the new table, then even it wont effect its parent table data.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Microsoft SQL 2005 Administrative GUI to get assistance in order to easily add new database table with all the specification you need e.g. Colum Name, Primary Key, Constraints etc. You can also use [CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx).  You can add as many new database tables you want without affecting any data stored in other database tables.

You can have look at [example discussed earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413244/how-do-i-create-a-simple-table-in-sql-server-2005).